# How to portably share a variable between threads/processes?

Tags: c, windows, unix

I have a server that spawns a new process or thread for every incoming request and I need to read and write a variable defined in this server from both threads and processes. Since the server program needs to work both on UNIX and Windows I need to share the variable in a portable way, but how do I do it?

I need to use the standard C library or the native syscalls, so please don’t suggest third party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

[shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) is operating system specific. On Linux, consider reading [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and (since with shared memory you always need some way to synchronize) [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html).

Of course you need to find out the similar (but probably not equivalent) Windows function calls.

Notice that [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) are not the same as [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). Threads by definition share a common single [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space). With threads, the main issue is then mostly synchronization, often using [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex) (e.g. [`pthread_mutex_lock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html) etc...). On Linux, read a [pthread tutorial](http://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads) & [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)

Recall that several libraries ([glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/), [QtCore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcore-index.html), [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/), ...) provide useful abstractions above operating system specific functionalities, but you seem to want avoiding them.

At last, I am not at all sure that sharing a variable like you ask is the best way to achieve your goals (I would definitely consider some [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) approach with an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop): [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) & [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), perhaps with a [textual protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) à la [JSON](http://json.org/)).

Comment: +1. The nearly-equivalent Windows side is also done through memory mapped files, using calls to [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx), [`CreateFileMapping()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx), [`MapViewOfFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx), etc. The sync stuff, however, is markedly different (semaphores and mutexes are created as global kernel objs with configured security descriptors, not just stored in shared mem). Nice answer, btw.

Comment: you could save a lot of execution time by creating a pool of threads/ids and using that pool, rather than spending time creating a thread in readtime (which also has to be destroyed in realtime)